# Azure Storage Explorer - Filtering on Last Modified

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Apparently we can not sort the blobs easily if there are more than 1000 : you will need to "load more" until the complete list of blob appears and then you can sort them as you wish. Which is really not ideal.

So I want to apply a filter on the 'Last Modified' tag key. But I can't seem to be able to make it work.

I want to get all the blobs from 1st of June and later.

Here I have (at least) 2 blobs from 4th of June 2021 (the displays is set on the french format, but the timestamp shouldn't be impacted) :

[image: 1]

But whatever filter I try I get nothing :

[image: 2]

I tried different formats but none are working :

- Last Modified >= 2021-06-01
- Last Modified >= 01-06-2021
- Last Modified >= 01/06/2021

Any ideas on what's going on here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas on what's going on here?

I believe the issue is that you're trying to filter by `LastModified` system property of the blob. You can also define tags for a blob and the screenshot you shared is for filtering of blobs based on the tag name/value specified for the blob.

To make the filtering work by tags, you will need to define tags for the blobs and then apply the filtering on those tag name/value.

Comment: And do you know if it is possible to sort / filter on the system properties ?

All I need to do is being able to retrieve ALL the blobs between two dates. It's quite incredible that this very basic need cannot be done using the dedicated "microsoft azure storage explorer" application (I guess the "microsoft" here is a hint on why I have these issues)

Comment: `And do you know if it is possible to sort / filter on the system properties ?` - Sadly no. Only system property you can filter on is the name of the blob (Prefix filtering in your screenshot) and no server side sorting support.